# Ограничение величины числа | C#

Tags: c#, типы-данных, типы, double

При работе мне понадобился такой тип, который может хранить ооочень большие числа. Для этого я использовал double, но теперь мне и его не хватает. А с этими большими числами мне нужно проводить некоторые операции:
-сложение
-преобразования типов данных( из него в string и обратно)
и тд
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу поступить?
Спасибо за любую помощь.
P.S.Нужна точность до единиц.(После запятой не важно)

Comment: мне нужна точность до единиц(после запятой не важно), будет ли он обеспечивать такую точность?

Comment: Возьмите Питон - там целые числа бесконечные и работа со строками удобная %)

Comment: Нужно уточнить, идёт ли речь об очень больших числах (больше, чем от ±5,0 × 10Е-324 до ±1,7 × 10Е308 у double), или о большом количестве значащих цифр.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь идёт не о величине чила, как обозначено в вопросе, а о количестве значащих цифр, как можно было бы подумать, то:
Учитывая, что у double 15-17 значащих цифр, вы можете использовать decimal c 28 значащими цифрами (не важно, до запятой или после). Ну а потом уже BigInteger.
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types

Answer (score 0):

Если идёт речь прям про очень большие числа советую использовать string, да..да.. именно строки. Реализуйте метод основанный на чистой логике сложения/вычитания/деления/умножения столбиком. Тогда у вас практически исчезнет ограничение длины числа. В интернете полно примеров как можно это реализовать, и в этом нет ничего сложного. Double и decimal - это конечно числовые типы данных, но компилируются они по разному и каждый имеет свои ограничения.

Comment: Это тоже хороший вариант

Comment: Помню, в начале 90-ых, когда была бешенная инфляция и много нулей в ценниках, попросили сделать чековую программу для аптеки на компьютере АГАТ (аналог Apple II). Вот тогда-то и пришлось самому на ассемблере писать библиотеку для работы с числами с большим количеством значащих цифр.

Comment: @rotabor Вы сколько лет в программировании?

Comment: Вот и посчитай...